# How to read multiple text files using window batch scripting?

Tags: batch-file

Currently I am trying to read the variable value from different text files available in my directly folder and use those variable to execute commands like uploading the content to FTP server.

I have different FTP servers on which I need to upload the same set of files. So what I want is to read the hostname, userID and password of different FTP servers which are saved in different text files and use those values to execute same set of commands for all.

Here is my FileUpload.bat looks like :-

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Anivirus_Upload\text_*.txt)
    do ( 
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%%~Fx") 
        do (
            if "%%A"="user" set user=%%B
                if "%%A"="password" set password=%%B
                if "%%A"="localPath" set localPath=%%B
                if "%%A"="serverpath" set serverpath=%%B
                if "%%A"="Hostname" set Hostname=%%B    
                echo  user %user%> ftpcmd.dat
                echo %password%>> ftpcmd.dat
                echo lcd %localPath%>>ftpcmd.dat
                echo cd %serverpath%/>>ftpcmd.dat
                echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
                echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
                ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %Hostname%
                del ftpcmd.dat
            ) 
    )
```

In the folder I have different text files namely

```
text_1 
text_2
```

etc and each text file have values like :-

```
user=XXXX
Hostname=10.164.XXXXX
password=XXXXX
localPath=C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Service_Pack_74
serverpath=Temp/XXXX/Service_Pack_74/
```

I don't know where I am messing with the code while reading multiple text files.

I checked my batch file with single text file and I am able to upload the content correctly so seems the issue is with the external for loop to read multiple files from the directory.

Comment: Not the answer to your question but a way to make what your doing "easier" Instead of having the files set up with "user=XXXX
Hostname=10.164.XXXXX
password=XXXXX
localPath=C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Service_Pack_74
serverpath=Temp/XXXX/Service_Pack_74/" then doing just put a set infront of each line in the text file. now instead of making it read the file then just call it as a bat file. <- what i did when i wanted to do what your trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things amiss here.

First, the `do (` **must** be on the same physical line as the `for`.

Next, the `delims` clause of the second `for` loop should be `delims=="`. With only 1 <kbd>=</kbd> delimiters are turned off, hence `%%A` will be assigned the contents of the entire line and `%%B` will be interpreted as the literal string `%B`. **AND** to assign value to the metavariables, you need to add a `tokens` clause specifying which tokens to assign.

Next, within a block (a parenthesised series of commands) any `%var%` is replaced by the contents of the variable `var` at the time the block is entered, not to any new value it adopts as the block is executed.

Next, the entire output and ftp section will be executed for each line of the file. Any output would depend on the value originally assigned to the variables you are using - possibly from a previous run.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Anivirus_Upload\text_*.txt) do ( 
 for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ("%%~Fx") do (
  if "%%A"=="user" set user=%%B
  if "%%A"=="password" set password=%%B
  if "%%A"=="localPath" set localPath=%%B
  if "%%A"=="Hostname" set Hostname=%%B    
  if "%%A"=="serverpath" (
   set serverpath=%%B
   echo user !user!> ftpcmd.dat
   echo !password!>> ftpcmd.dat
   echo lcd !localPath!>>ftpcmd.dat
   echo cd !serverpath!/>>ftpcmd.dat
   echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
   echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
   ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat !Hostname!
   del ftpcmd.dat
  ) 
 )
)
```

Note here that the `ftp` command file is built and executed using `!var!` which accesses the changed value of the variables when `delayedexpansion` is in effect.

I have no idea what you want in your ftp-`put` command. As it is, the routine will substitute whatever is the first parameter to the batch file for `%1`

I'm also assuming that each variable is guaranteed to appear in each file, and that the `serverpath` will be last in that file.

Comment: Thanks Magoo I changed my script as per the suggestion by you and also tried the solution you provided but it keeps on throwing a message "user" was unexpected at this time.
I did my analysis and tried and checked for null values that could cause such a problem .

Comment: There was another error with your code (which I simply copied and edited) - the syntax of `if` requires a double-`=` not a single. That would lead to the message you describe.

Comment: You can use  EQU  in place of the ==